# Resizing my linux partition

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-7, lubuntu

So, I was getting rid of my openSUSE to install lubuntu. In the process, I didn't manage my hard drive partitions well enough and as a result, I lost my windows 7 partition. I got over the loss, and formatted my entire hard drive by install lubuntu over all the space. (I tried first installing windows 7, but I kept getting some weird errors during the partitioning process). I was wondering now if I could resize my lubuntu partition so I can install windows 7 again.

Here is a gparted screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone help me out? I have all my Linux disks and my windows disks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize a mounted partition and since you are already in Ubuntu, the / partition is mounted. What you need to do is to boot into live by making a USB bootable with Ubuntu and launch gparted from there. In gparted, right-click your /dev/sda4 and you can resize it according to your wish.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the "boot into live" part. Can I just boot into my lubuntu cd? And does lubuntu have gparted already installed on it? If not, I also have the ubuntu cd. Does the ubuntu cd have gparted already installed onto it?

Comment: Booting into the CD is what we meant by 'boot into live'. :) Live means that the system will be running from the RAM and not the hard disk. Usually, the disks have gparted on them. Do try booting into it and see.

Answer (score 0):

In order to adjust your disc partitions with Gparted, the disc needs to be accessed from 'outside' as it were. You do this by getting Ubuntu going from the Live CD (ie 'boot into live') and then run Gparted from there. Ubuntu is then running from RAM rather than your hard disc.
If dev/sda1 still exists as your screenshot shows, you should be able to reinstate your old Win7 to that ntfs partition.
And yes, you can resize your Ubuntu partition, but only by using the Live CD as in paragraph 1.

Comment: de1337ed does not want to delete his lubuntu, it seems and /dev/sda1 is the boot partition, so you probably won't be able to install windows 7 on /dev/sda1 without causing unnecessary damage, right?

Comment: @Jobin read my message/comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I would suggest you, in case you can bear to lose your data(seems like you don't have much left ;-)), is first cleaning up your entire disk using [gparted](http://www.gparted.sourceforge.net/) by inserting your Lubuntu or Windows 7 CD/DVD/USB and then installing Windows 7 followed by Lubuntu after checking what errors you are getting about `partitioning` while installing Windows 7.

Comment: Lies.  `/dev/sda1` does NOT need win7 allocation.  I have win7 as `/dev/sda3` on my dual-boot system, and it works perfectly fine.  In fact, I'm on it now.  (order of operations: (1) New drive, (2) Install Ubuntu with custom partitioning, (3) install Win7 using advanced partition selection in the Windows installer, (4) reinstall GRUB bootloader, (5) dualboot is now awesome)  (image of proof, from Windows, with Paragon Partition Manager: http://i645.photobucket.com/albums/uu172/trekcaptainusa/partitionlayout_zps4534cf70.png )

Comment: @TheLordofTime: Thanks a lot, you corrected one of my age-old myths.

Comment: Yeppers, if I `fdisk -L` it on Ubuntu it will show the `/dev/sdaX` stuff, which I hand-copied into the screengrab from Windows, and added in the equiv. `sdaX` numbering, since not even Paragon can `fdisk -L` from Windows

Comment: Notes: My setup was a clean drive.  To replicate this on an already-setup drive, it could be difficult, and you have a high possibility of data loss when you aren't doing a clean install.

Comment: @TheLordofTime: Do you mean you set up Windows on a clean drive? Seems unlikely as your sda3 has been occupied by "C". So what do you mean your "setup" was a clean drive?

Comment: Clean drive as in stock OEM blank drive from TigerDirect, partition table created on Linux, with ext4+swap as sda1/sda2.  Remaining blank space used by Windows, created C:/ and System Reserved, resulting in sda3/sda4 respectively.  Replicating my setup will require the partition table to be nuked, and data backed up first, but it is a proof-of-concept of windows on sda3 and sda4